# Coloring issue when setting Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, listview, android-styles

i've a main activity xml which shows 2 button and 1 `EditText` and another layout with `listview`. The problem is my buttons and `listview` texts are white. I don't know how to resolve this.

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#009688</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00796b</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

activity_main.xml (Design view)

[image]

You can see here, button isn't visible. But, if i give background as black it shows,

[image]

So, i don't want to give the background for each element because that's not a good solution.

Another activity with listactivity :

[image]

Here, the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you use some dark theme instead of light

Comment: What would be the apt theme? can you name it

Answer (score 0):

For your ListView, you can overrider the getView method of the Adapter, then set the TextView color in code.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList) {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);        
    text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);        
    return view;
  }
};
```

And for your button

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

or in xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybtn" 
    android:text="text"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:textColor="#000000" />  <-- set color here -->
```

Alternatively, your could try using a dark theme such as

```
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
```

Comment: I don't want to set color for each element because i've many elements in many layouts. Any other solution?

Comment: I guess you could use a dark theme. Although, for the button, it's just one row of copy/paste. If you don't have 100 layouts to change it would have been quicker to change them as I suggested than going through the effort of creating a question about it on SO. @user3289108

Comment: Ok, can you name the dark theme? i try it.

Comment: It changed for listview. But, for button..only white background with transparent text.

Comment: So use `android:textColor="#000000"` for the button @user3289108